# Why does the button not work in Google Assistant?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I attempt to add a button onto my action on Google assistant, but the code only works for the first one. Here is where I add in the button for the ones that don't work:

```
'Biology': {
title: 'Biology',
text:'Press the button to visit our site for more info. Biology is an important subject for those who are willing to take it, and this website will provide you' +
'with the necessary skill for this subject.',
image: new Image({
  url: 'https://www.edzuki.com/biology/Biology+Edzuki.jpg',
  alt: 'Biology as a subject',
}),
button: new Button({
  title:'Click for the Biology Page',
  url: 'https://www.edzuki.com/biology/',
}),
```

and, for some reason, this one works

```
'Art': {
title: 'Art',
text:'Press the button to visit our site for more info. Art is an important subject for those who are willing to take it, and this website will provide you' +
'with the necessary skill for this subject.',
image: new Image({
  url: 'https://www.edzuki.com/art/Art.jpg',
  alt: 'Art as a subject',
}),
buttons: new Button({
title: 'Click for Art',
url: `https://www.edzuki.com/art/`,
}),
display: 'WHITE',
},
```

for const subjectCard (a basic card).
No errors are thrown by the assistant, just no button is visible. Why is this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "only works for the first one" but later say "no button at all"? Can you show the rest of the code illustrating the entire command that includes adding the button?

Comment: It still isn't clear what you mean by "only works for the first one" and "no button at all", or what the rest of your code looks like. It makes it very difficult for us to try and duplicate your problem to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you use the key `button` for your button, but in the second example you use `buttons` with an 's'. The docs also suggest you should be using the plural version `buttons` and your own code should show you this works based on your second working example

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card

e.g

```
'Biology': {
title: 'Biology',
text:'Press the button to visit our site for more info. Biology is an important subject for those who are willing to take it, and this website will provide you' +
'with the necessary skill for this subject.',
image: new Image({
  url: 'https://www.edzuki.com/biology/Biology+Edzuki.jpg',
  alt: 'Biology as a subject',
}),
buttons: new Button({
  title:'Click for the Biology Page',
  url: 'https://www.edzuki.com/biology/',
}),
```